# How to enter text in Slickgrid cell

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, slickgrid

I am working on an AngularJS app that has a Slickgrid on it.  I am trying to write a test and im running into a problem.  When I use Selenium I can get it to click in one of the cells but the sendkeys function doesn't seem to do anything, no text is entered even though I can see the cursor flashing in the cell.

Even if I record my actions in Selenium IDE, no actions are recorded for entering text in the cell.

I've tried opening the JavaScript console in chrome and writing some JavaScript to enter some text in one of the cells and made zero progress (I don't know JavaScript).

What JavaScript can I use in the chrome console to enter text in one of the cells?  Does selenium not work well with SlickGrid?

I'm not sure what the best approach is here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are asking about two things at once. I will try to emphasize that I have no experience in Selenium, but I can try answering the JavaScript part.

You didn't share too much information about your actual SlickGrid setup, so my solutions for your question are based on the official [SlickGrid: Making it editable](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html) example, which you could try these methods on, for instance using the JavaScript [ScratchPad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad).

I will share the two methods I have found, since I don't know which one could you integrate to your Selenium setup.

---

**Method 1** - via the [SlickGrid API](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/API-Reference):

```
var row = 0;
var cell = 0;
var test_input = 'Your input';

if(grid.canCellBeActive(row, cell)) {
    grid.setActiveCell(row, cell);

    grid.editActiveCell();

    var activeCell = $(grid.getActiveCellNode());
    if(typeof activeCell !== 'undefined') {
        activeCell.children(0).val(test_input);
        grid.gotoCell(row, cell);
    }
}
```

**Method 2** - via setting the [data source](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#constructor) of your grid.

In this case it's a JavaScript array of objects:

```
var row = 0;
var test_input = 'Your input';

data[row].title = test_input;
grid.invalidateRow(row);
grid.render();
```

These two methods both change the given cell data, the main difference is that using the second method you need to rely on the field name *property* you want to set.